# Read keyboard input in R

Tags: r

I have the following code which basically reads two inputs, `a` and `b`, from keyboard for the future use. However, when I ran the entire code R automatically reads the following two rows of the code as my keyboard input. How can I fix this?

```
{a = as.numeric(readline("ID: ")); b = readline("Date MM/DD/YY: ")}
ytm = nlminb(0, yield, ID = a, date = b, lower = 0, upper = 1)
YTM = ytm$par
```

Answer (score 0):

If I select those three lines in RStudio and press CTRL-ENTER, then it does as you reported, treating the following two lines as console input.  However, if I place the contents into a file and then `source()` that file, it prompts me for ID and Date as expected.